# node.js socket.io apache server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have some sort of noob question regarding to node.js and socket.io. These two guys are usually needed to use websockets for server to browser communication. Once that my project gets done, do I have to upload my php files to my apache server. Now my question is do I have also to upload my node_modules directory to my apache server? along with socket.io directory?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your node.js process you need to have ability to execute own applications on server. Classic virtual server does not allow of such functionality. There is virtual server hosting for node.js specifically, check out nodejitsu, heroku or any other.

You can run node.js as web platform by it self, without of use of any apache, that will make your life much easier. But if you still need apache and PHP, then you need to consider proxying from apache to your node.js process. This still can be tricky as proxying WebSockets is not straight forward.

If you have access to Apache settings, then you can enable proxying for HTTP/HTTPS, read this: http://ronenagranat.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/apache2-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs.html
For WebSockets, there is not much data available but here is possible solution: http://blog.cafarelli.fr/post/2013/04/26/Backporting-Apache-support-for-websockets-reverse-proxy-(aka-getting-GateOne-to-work-behind-Apache)

Although if you have own server and have ability to choose between web platform, I would recommend to look into nginx, as it has support for WebSockets proxying (might require module and nginx recompiling).